# Edit ffmpeg arguments while playing

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js

I am building a client (discord.js) that plays music from youtube. Before the client starts playing the ffmpeg-arguments (filters etc.) can be edited and piped into the stream. I use **prism-media** (npm) to define the args.

My Question: How is it possible to edit these arguments while the client is playing? f.ex. **disable in the middle of a song** etc...

The code basically looks like in the Readme example on github: https://github.com/amishshah/prism-media/tree/dev

Comment: I don't think you can modify ffmpeg's settings while its going. You would need to stop the process, update the arguments, and start it again.

Comment: Did you figure something out? what kind of changed do you want to do?

Comment: @MattiasWadman just some filters (-af)

Answer (score 0):

Not in general but some filters have support for something called "commands" that can be sent while transcoding to do various things.

Have a look at the these command filters an examples 
[sendcmd and asendcmd](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd)
[zmq and azmq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zmq_002c-azmq).